# Url.Route in ApiController doesn't include hostname

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

From an `ApiController`, I am generating a password reset link that is emailed to the user.  Everything works except the `Url.Route` function doesn't generate the link with the hostname.  I'm not sure if it's because I'm using `localhost` that's causing the problem.

This is the code to generate the link

```
string callbackUrl  = Url.Route("DefaultApi", new { controller = "Account", action= "ResetPassword", UserId = user.Id, code = code });
```

This is the link that is generated

```
https:///api/Account/ResetPassword?UserId=aaaaaaaaaa&code=aaaaaaaaa
```

Notice the `https:///api`, it should include the hostname and port like `https://localhost:4040/api`. Why isn't the hostname being included?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Url.Route` generates relative urls only. To get absolute url, use `Url.Link`:

```
string callbackUrl  = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { controller = "Account", action= "ResetPassword", UserId = user.Id, code = code });
```